# deep copy of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, deep-copy

I am using a Fragment class.
I add it using

```
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


         Search fragment = new  Search(maincontrolActivity.this);

          fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragment , "MY_FRAG");
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
          this.FragmentObject = fragment
```

when I do refresh the control,I recall this code but by passing `this.FragmentObject` but I think it be garbage collected because the = refere to the same object , and when say add, it free the old fragement which is the same

so do I need a deep copy or any way to refresh ?

any idea

Comment: I'd say you are approaching the problem incorrectly. Why not have a `refreshData` method inside your fragment that causes it to refresh its `View`s and repopulate the data? Instead of recreating the entire fragment which causes a lot of overhead...

Comment: @SalilPandit could u give me example

Comment: the problem is that I have many fragments , u mean in each fragment ,I put my datarefresher method or something like that

Comment: Yeah thats an option. am I right in guessing you're applying some kind of filter that is requiring the data to be updated? Maybe a location or something?

Comment: no I have main scree nthat contains buttons and menue, so when click I fill layout with the desired fragment, the custoemr askemd me to put refresh button on the main screen such that when click the button , I refresh the fragment , the problem is that the fragments is different in the contained data , so I thought about reload the fragment

Comment: Is the refresh button in the `Activity` layout or the `Fragment` layout? (this will help me give you a code example...)

Comment: @SalilPandit the refresh button in the Activity layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So what I would do is have an `Interface` defined and have each `Fragment` register with the `Activity` for a callback when the refresh button is clicked. Then in the fragment itself have it refresh its data. If that means getting new data, switch to a `ProgressBar`, get the data from the server, and repopulate the `View`s. [Here is an entire article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on creating `Interface`s in `Activities` and calling `Fragment`s from them.
Here is roughly what your code will look like...
The `Activity`:

```
public class RefreshActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.refresh_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public interface OnRefreshPressedListener {
        public void onRefreshPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((OnRefreshPressedListener)this.FragmentObject).onRefreshPressed();
    }
}
```

The `Fragment`:

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements OnRefreshPressedListener {

    @Override
    public void onRefreshPressed() {
        //TODO: Refresh your data!

    }

}
```